# Empty set operations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Could anyone correct me?

$∅ × ∅ = ∅$

${\{∅\}} × {\{\{∅\}\}} = \{∅, \{∅\}\}$

$∅^{\{∅\}} = ∅$

$\{∅\}^{\{∅\}} = \{\{∅, ∅\}\}$

$\{∅\} - P(\{∅\}) = ∅$

$2^{\{\{\{\}\}\}} = \{∅, \{\{\{\}\}\}\}$

Comment: What definition of pair are you using?

Comment: All except the last one here make sense to me. I have no idea what you mean by the last one. Is $\{\}$ meant to be the empty set?

Comment: {} should be equal to ∅

Answer (score 0):

$\{∅\} × \{\{∅\}\} = \{(∅, \{∅\})\}$

$\{∅\}^{\{∅\}} = \{(∅, ∅)\}$

$2^{\{\{\{\}\}\}} = \{∅, \{\{\{\}\}\}\}$
Do you mean
$2^{\{\{∅\}\}} = \{∅, \{\{∅\}\}\}$?

Comment: I have no more specification for {{{}}}. But {} is equal to ∅?

Comment: Define the improper expression {}.